# Azure blob image - poor quality when loaded into flash

Tags: php, flash, azure, actionscript-2, azure-blob-storage

I've got several image stored in the azure blob. When I navigate to the URL trough a web-browser, the quality is good.

But when I load the image into a flash movie, it has got a poor quality.
http://tiptile-dev.azurewebsites.net/viewer/index.php

I have a copy of the same flash movie that loads the images from a folder on the server, there I also get a good quality (that is, if the image has a good quality).
http://www.tiptileonline.com/viewer/?id=E6E4D2C1-F6A5-42D6-9099-4D3DBCB24758

To see the difference, have a look at the "S" image.

I suspect, that the image from the blob storage is dowloading as a stream (first low quality, and it gets better and better as time(microseconds) passes by). Is this correct? And (how) can I turn the streaming off so the image gets downloaded as is.

NB: yes I know, flash should not be used anymore. We are working on a HTML5(-canvas) solution but for the time being I want to get the flash to work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe the issue is related to Azure Storage. To verify maybe just have your HTML5 app serve the image and I believe you will see the same quality as you get when you open the image directly from the browser.

I found this article that has some hints on image processing within Flash - maybe that will help. http://helpx.adobe.com/flash/kb/improving-bitmap-image-quality-flash.html.